# Docusign: Is there a way to create an envelope in the 'created' state and then put it into 'sent' later?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I want to be able to create an envelope and then email the link to the signer. The code segment I came up with is:

```
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();

        envDef.Status = "sent";
        EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);

        RecipientViewRequest viewOptions = new RecipientViewRequest()
        {
            ReturnUrl = "https://www.docusign.com/devcenter", 
            ClientUserId = signer.ClientUserId,
            AuthenticationMethod = "email",
            UserName = signer.Name,
            Email = signer.Email // does NOT send an email
        };

        ViewUrl recipientView = envelopesApi.CreateRecipientView(accountId, envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId, viewOptions);
```

The code before this segment gets the account, signer an envelope definition, etc.

This code works fine if I set envDef.Status = "sent". If I do not set that status, I get an exception from the last line of code in this segment.

I want to just have the envelope go into created status, then get the URL and send the email in my own code that does relay email.

Or, can I supply an email address and have Docusign send the email? But, in that case, what if their email fails for some reason?

The bottom line is that I want a way to deal with the problem of how to re-send the link if the email fails to get sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re your stated objective:

> I want to just have the envelope go into created status, then get the URL and send the email in my own code that does relay email.

This approach is not recommended, since the URL that you obtain via `CreateRecipientView` will timeout in a short amount of time (I believe it's 5 minutes).  In other words, if the recipient does not open the email that you send them and click the link to launch their signing session within that period of time, the link becomes invalid and they'll be unable to use it to access their signing session.

Instead of using `CreateRecipientView`, I'd recommend that you simply specify the recipient's info (name, email, etc.) as part of the envelope definition and then DocuSign will send the recipient an email that contains a link that they can use to access their Envelope. This link will be valid for days (not minutes, like the link that you generate yourself via `CreateRecipientView`), so there's no requirement that the signer act on it immediately. If for some reason the recipient misplaces or does not receive the email that DocuSign sends them, you can easily have DocuSign re-send that email notification by either using the DocuSign web UI or by using the `UpdateRecipient` API operation with `resendEnvelope=true` specified (as Frederic described in his answer).

---

**Update #1**

There's no way to retrieve a long-lived link that a recipient can use to initiate their signing session. A common way to address your scenario would be the following:

- Send the signer an email that contains a link that leads them to a web page that you build -- and instructions for them to click that link to launch their Envelope ***whenever they are ready to review/sign the document(s)***. (The link URL would need to contain some sort of querystring parameters that your web page could use to identify the Envelope and Recipient.)
- Design your web page such that when it receives an inbound request (as it would when the recipient clicks the link in the email you send them), it uses the information in the querystring parameters to identify the Envelope and Recipient, then issues a `CreateRecipientView` request to retrieve the URL that will launch that recipient's signing session, and finally, automatically redirects the user to the URL that the `CreateRecipientView` response returns, thereby opening the Envelope for the recipient to review/sign/submit.

By following a process like this, you're able to craft/send the email that the recipient receives (instead of relying upon DocuSign to do so), and can ensure that you're only retrieving the envelope URL whenever the user has indicated that they're ready to sign (thereby avoiding the potential of the short-lived link expiring before it's used).

---

**Update #2**

For an example of how to add recipient(s) to the `EnvelopeDefinition` object using the DocuSign C# SDK, see this "[recipe](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/test/Recipes/CoreRecipes.cs)" -- specifically, see the code within the [requestSignatureOnDocumentTest](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/0b7ab3a511073a2a4a813f8586917817e492810c/test/Recipes/CoreRecipes.cs#L101) method. It's basically a two-step process:

1) Define each recipient. For example:

```
// Add a recipient to sign the documeent
Signer signer = new Signer();
signer.Email = recipientEmail;
signer.Name = recipientName;
signer.RecipientId = "1";
```

2) Populate the `Recipients` property of the `EnvelopeDefinition` object with the recipient(s) that you create. For example:

```
envDef.Recipients = new Recipients();
envDef.Recipients.Signers = new List<Signer>();
envDef.Recipients.Signers.Add(signer);
```

Comment: My superiors may not want to send the email using Docusign. Is there a way to get a link that does not timeout in a short time?

Comment: Kim, thank you for figuring out a way I could do what I requested. Having seen your idea, I think I should just send the email through the Docusign API. But, I don't see how to do that. Can you point me to the documentation that will allow me to send the email? Also, can I create the envelope with status = 'created' in one step, and then have the email sent using the API?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include more info.  If this addresses your question, please mark the answer as "Accepted" so that others are more likely to benefit from this Q&A in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again, Kim, for responding. I know how to add recipients. I don't know how to send the email using the Docusign API. As my code example shows, I was hoping to get a URL and email it myself. Now I want to use the Docusign API. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The same “recipe” code sample that I linked to in my second update shows exactly how to use the API to create and send the Envelope. Basically, as long as you set envelope status to *sent* and do NOT specify the *clientUserId* property for the recipient(s), DocuSign will create the envelope and send it (i.e., send the signing invitation email to the recipient(s)). See the code sample I linked to for an example of how this is done.

Comment: Wow, I almost missed the comment about clientUserId. I was assigning one to get the URL. So, that comment answers my question, along with the comment on the fact that the URL I was getting would expire. How do I mark the comments as an Answer?

Comment: I selected this answer because it addressed the bigger problem I was facing for my project, even though the 2nd answer was probably the technically correct answer to my answer. The point is that when I found out that the URL I was creating was only good for 5 minutes, I no longer wanted to email that URL. I had to use Docusign to send the link. The key to fixing an issue in my code is in one of the comments. I was assigning a clientUserId in order to get the URL. I had to leave that property empty in order for the email to get sent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to answer both of your inquiries :

*1) The bottom line is that I want a way to deal with the problem of how to re-send the link if the email fails to get sent.*

In order to re-send the DocuSign email to your recipients, you can use the `UpdateRecipient()` method as such (see my C# example below). This will re-trigger the signing email to be sent one more time to the transaction recipients :

```
RecipientsUpdateSummary recipientsUpdateSummary = 
                envelopeApi.UpdateRecipients(
                    accountId, 
                    envelope.EnvelopeId, 
                    envelope.Recipients, 
                    new EnvelopesApi.UpdateRecipientsOptions { resendEnvelope = "true" });
```

Here is what the [official documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/update/) states :

[image]

2)  *Is there a way to create an envelope in the 'created' state and then put it into 'sent' later?*

Yes, it is possible.
When you create your envelope, make sure to specify the "Created" status as below :

```
Status = "created"
```

Create your envelope :

```
envelopeApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelope);
```

Then, when you're ready, change the envelope status to "sent". This will trigger the emails to the recipients. Voila !

```
Envelope updatedEnvelope = new Envelope
            {
                Status = "sent"
            };
            envelopeApi.Update(
                accountId,
                envelopeId,
                updatedEnvelope);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. Please clarify the following: (1) do both code examples send the email using the Docusign site, as opposed to me sending a relay email? (2) If the envelope is created and sent in two steps, does the link expire quickly, like Kim said?